# Duda sobre herencia en Python

Tags: python-3.x, herencia

Haciendo referencia a la herencia en Python me han surgido dos preguntas

**Primera duda**:

- No entiendo por qué al ejecutar el siguiente código el resultado es:

> amarillo

> amarillo

La clase BBB hereda de la AAA. Inicio el constructor de super con color = 'rojo'. Al llamar el método getColor() tenemos el return de amarillo, correcto. Pero al llamar el método getColor2() heredado de la clase BBB que ha sido inicializado con color 'rojo' ¿Por qué obtengo el color 'amarillo'?

Si modifico el nombre de la variable color en AAA o BBB el resultado es correcto, pero pensaba que no tendría que ser necesario.

```
class AAA:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def getColor2(self):
        return self.color


class BBB(AAA):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__(color="rojo")
        self.color = color

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color


insB = BBB(color="amarillo")

print(insB.getColor())
print(insB.getColor2())
```

**Segunda duda:**

Otra duda que me ha surgido es: Si la superclase y la subclase tienen un método que se llama igual, ¿qué forma tengo de diferenciarlos al hacer una llamada del método desde la instancia de la subclase? Un ejemplo de esto teniendo en cuenta el codigo anterio sería si getColor2 se pasase a llamar getColor.

Comment: Recuerda que debe haber una sola pregunta por publicacion. Si tenes otra duda, tendrias que hacer otra publicacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un objeto sólo puede tener un atributo de un nombre dado, como `color` por ejemplo, sin importar cuantos niveles de herencia.

En el `__init__()` de `BBB`

```
class BBB(AAA):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__(color="rojo")
        self.color = color
```

la llamada a `super()` deja `self.color` en `rojo`, pero luego de inmediato lo cambias a `amarillo` con

```
        self.color = color
```

Los métodos de un objeto también son atributos, y si tienes dos métodos de igual nombre en distintos niveles de la jerarquía, sólo el último será reconocido.

Puede que haya una forma de tener dos métodos con igual nombre y poder llamarlos indistintamente, pero me parece una falla de diseño el que necesites tal cosa.